# Adding Azure Key Vault connected service inside visual studio will keep showing "Verifying that your application will have access to the key vault"

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio, azure-keyvault

I want to add a key vault connected service inside visual studio, but when i do so i keep receiving this screen:-

[image]

and nothing will be added to my project? any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added your user account logged in VS to the Access policy of the azure keyvault, if not, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal) to add it.

If it still not work, navigate to the azure keyvault in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> add an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor` to your user account, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal#grant-access)(your user account logged in azure portal need to be the `Owner/User Access administrator` to do this operation).

Comment: I have full access but still stuck as above.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My VS account had the "Owner" Azure role assigned to the Key Vault, so I thought it is sufficient. However, VS was stuck on the "Dependency configuration progress" window when adding the Key Vault as a connected service.

I have added the "Key Vault Secrets User" role to my account, and the configuration has been successful. You apparently need a "secrets/key user" role to effectively use KV. For my Managed Identity I also had to add the "Key Vault Reader" role, but VS connected services do not seem to need that one.

Comment: This was what worked for me too. So weird. You'd think being "Owner" would suffice.

Comment: This worked for me too! Also had Owner and then added Key Vault User. Then the key vault could be added